# Change `lstlistoflistings` numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

I'm using the `listings` package to format program code in LaTeX and the list of listings at the end is numbered like this:

```
3.1 Code A
3.2 Code B
3.3 Code C
4.1 Code D
4.2 Code E
```

It starts the numbering again at each chapter. However, I need the numbering scheme to look like this:

```
Listing 1 Code A
Listing 2 Code B
Listing 3 Code C
Listing 4 Code D
Listing 5 Code E
```

I already tried the recommended solution from other questions:

```
\renewcommand*{\thelisting}{\sffamily\small\arabic{listing}}
% or
\renewcommand*{\thelstlisting}{\sffamily\small\arabic{lstlisting}}
```

However, both commands return `LaTeX Error: \thelstlisting undefined. [\renewcommand*{\thelstlisting}]` (or `thelisting` for the first command).

Is there any other approach how to accomplish this?

Note that I'm using a custom document class from my university, just ask if you need any information from it.

**Edit:**

The following packages are included by my document:

```
inputenc, ulem, listings, textcomp, color, courier, url, tabto, multirow, tabularx, xcolor, amssymb, pifont, rotating, enumitem, chngcntr
```

The following packages are included by the document class:

```
remreset, scrhack, color, xcolor, xifthen, ifpdf, wallpaper, palatino, scrpage2, acronym, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amstext, babel, array, iftex, hyperref, graphicx
```

Comment: In “3.1” is 3 the chapter number? Nice avatar, by the way! `:-)`

Comment: @egreg Thanks :). Yes, 3 is the chapter number

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage{chngcntr}` and then, after loading `listings`, `\counterwithout{lstlisting}{chapter}` Can you show a pointer to the class?

Comment: @egreg This produces the correct numbering, but I need the list to start with `Listing xx captionOfCodeA`. Currently it is `xx captionOfCodeA`

Comment: That's why something more is needed. Without knowing what packages the class loads and what class it's based on, it's a shot in the dark.

Comment: @egreg I added the loaded packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, but could require some adjustment according to settings made by the class you are using.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{listings}

\AtBeginDocument{% the counter is defined later
  \counterwithout{lstlisting}{chapter}%
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@lstlisting}[2]{%
  \@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{1.5em}{\lstlistingname\ #1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings

\chapter{A}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Code A]
xyz
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Code A]
xyz
\end{lstlisting}

\chapter{B}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Code A]
xyz
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Code A]
xyz
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is simpler solution to your problem with the chapternumbering. The `listings` package provides the `\lstset` command to configure the output. The  `numberbychapter=false` option does exactly whats advertised.

The Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[final]{listings}
\lstset{numberbychapter=false, captionpos=b, caption=\lstname,frame=single,%
numbers=left, stepnumber=1, numbersep=2pt, xleftmargin=15pt, framexleftmargin=15pt,%
numberstyle=\tiny, tabsize=4, columns=fixed,%
basicstyle={\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont\footnotesize},%
keywordstyle=\bfseries, commentstyle={\color[gray]{0.33}\itshape},%
stringstyle=\color[gray]{0.25}, breaklines, breakatwhitespace, breakautoindent}
\lstset{literate=
  {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
  {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
  {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
  {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
  {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
  {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
  {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
}
\lstloadlanguages{[ANSI]C, C++, [gnu]make, gnuplot, Matlab}

\begin{document}
\chapter{TEST}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,name={Example 1},label={sc:bsp}]
#include <iostream>

void SayHello(void)
{
    // Kommentar
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SayHello();
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\chapter{TEST}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,name={Example 2},label={sc:bsp}]
#include <iostream>

void SayHello(void)
{
    // Kommentar
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SayHello();
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\chapter{TEST}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,name={Example 3},label={sc:bsp}]
#include <iostream>

void SayHello(void)
{
    // Kommentar
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SayHello();
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\clearpage
\lstlistoflistings
\end{document}
```

The Output:
[image]

You most certainly dont need the complete lst-setup that I've provided. But it should give you a small overview what's possible.

**Update -- also adds entry-prefix for Listings**

To get the desired output, you have to have the `scrhack` package and a `scr`-class. Load the class with the `listof=entryprefix` option and specify the entry prefix with `\listoflolentryname`. The solution of egreg however tinkers far less with your existing document because it only redefines how a line is printed to your list of listings and therefore incorporated as your LoL.

```
\documentclass[listof=entryprefix]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[final]{listings}
\lstset{numberbychapter=false}
\lstloadlanguages{C++}

%Rename How the Code should be named
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
%rename how the List should be named
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Code}
%Add entry-prefix for listings
\newcommand\listoflolentryname\lstlistingname

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{TEST}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,name={Example 1}, caption={Example 1},label={sc:bsp}]
#include <iostream>

void SayHello(void)
{
    // Kommentar
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SayHello();
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\chapter{TEST}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,name={Example 2}, caption={Example 2},label={sc:bsp}]
#include <iostream>

void SayHello(void)
{
    // Kommentar
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SayHello();
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\chapter{TEST}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,name={Example 3}, caption={Example 3},label={sc:bsp}]
#include <iostream>

void SayHello(void)
{
    // Kommentar
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SayHello();
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\clearpage
\lstlistoflistings
\end{document}
```

Produces following output:
[image]

Comment: This results in the same as `\counterwithout{lstlisting}{chapter}` - the output doesn't show the text `Listing` before the (correctly) numbered listing entry. And since I'm using about a dozen different languages and `lstset` highlightings, this kind of configuration also seems to be counter-intuitive in my scenario. +1 anyways as it might be the correct solution for others.

Comment: Terribly sorry, my bad. I didn't read all the comments on your question. I'll edit my answer to incorporate also the second requirement.